# Context menu not showing submenu

Tags: jquery, html, css

In this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/lB4r7ipkoLnCbZ2DMTHM?p=preview) I have a menu that shows up when you click on the canvas. On hover over the "Aggregate" menu item, a second submenu shows up on the right.

The problem is that if you "mouse out" from "Aggregate" and then enter again, the position of the submenu is no longer where it is supposed to be. What's wrong with this code?

HTML

```
  <div id="canvas" style="width:400px;height:400px;background-color:#ff33ff;"></div>

    <div id="menu1" class="context-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);">Display</a>
        </li>
        <li id="li1">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);">Aggregate</a>
        </li>
        <li id="li2">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);">Order by</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);">Group by</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="menu2" class="context-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);">Count</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);">Sum</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);">Average</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#canvas').click(function(e) {

    var top = e.pageY;
    var left = e.pageX;

    $("#menu1").show();
    $("#menu1").offset({ top: top, left: left });

    $('#li1').mouseenter(function() {
          $("#menu2").offset({ top: top+20, left: left+120 });
            $("#menu2").show();
    });

    $('#li1').mouseleave(function() {
        $("#menu2").hide();
    });

    $('#menu2').mouseenter(function() {
            $("#menu2").show();
    });

    $('#menu2').mouseleave(function() {
            $("#menu2").hide();
    });

});
```

CSS

```
.context-menu {
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  background-color:#ffffff;
  padding:6px 0 0 0;
  display:none;
}
.context-menu ul {
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}
.context-menu li {
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
.context-menu li:hover {
  background-color:rgb(248,248,248);
}
.context-menu a {
  color:#333;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height:24px;
  margin-left:20px;
}
#menu1{
  position:absolute;
  width:140px;
}
#menu2{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
}
```

Comment: A lot of what you're attempting to do can be achieved with CSS. No need to use JS for hover states (mouse[enter|leave]). Although not a perfect example I did a [quick example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NrJ9P46R0YajtdEquFrj?p=preview).

Comment: thanks, I ended up implementing your idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `offset` with `css`.

I think every time `offset` is called on `mouseenter`, it adds to the current position of that menu.

Using the `css` method will **set the top and left positions** instead of adding to the current position.

Answer (score 1):

Place this line `$("#menu2").offset({ top: top+20, left: left+120 });` outside the `mouseenter` function to avoid it to be executed on each mouse enter.

```
$('#li1').mouseenter(function() {
    //$("#menu2").offset({ top: top+20, left: left+120 });
    $("#menu2").show();
});

$("#menu2").offset({ top: top+20, left: left+120 });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/62d1s0je/)

Comment: Thanks, that helps, however if I click again on the canvas and change the position of the menu the submenu doesn't show up correctly

Comment: I know... Was working on it... But the other answer is your solution ;) I upvoted @Mr. Meeseeks...